# Can a Huge (or larger) creature move through the Watery Sphere spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement, saving-throw, creature-size

The [*watery sphere*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/watery-sphere) spell description says:

> On a successful save, a creature is ejected from that space to the nearest unoccupied space of the creature’s choice outside the sphere. A Huge or larger creature succeeds on the saving throw automatically, [...]

Every time a Huge creature would attempt to go through the sphere - it will automatically make a successful save against the effect, and so will be moved back in unoccupied square?

Imagine a straight corridor 15 feet wide, and a Huge creature tried to go through it, but the path is blocked by *watery sphere*. Does this mean that a Huge creature cannot go through *watery sphere* at all?

Comment: And if it can't go through it, may a creature choose to squeeze to fit into the watery sphere in terms of pass through it in the next round?

Answer (score 6):

## The Huge or Larger creature can move through the sphere

The spell states:

> **On a successful save**, a creature is ejected from that space to the nearest unoccupied space of the creature’s choice outside the sphere. A Huge or larger creature **succeeds on the saving throw automatically**.

So the creature can choose to go back to the square it was just in, or to any other unoccupied square.

> Imagine a straight corridor 15 feet wide, and a Huge creature tried to go through it, but the path is blocked by watery sphere. Does this mean that a Huge creature cannot go through watery sphere at all?

A huge creature can step into the space occupied by the watery sphere, then they will automatically succeed the check, and can choose to move to an unoccupied space on the opposite side of the sphere. This doesn't block the creature.

Comment: The sphere has a 5 foot radius, why is the nearest unoccupied space on the other side of the sphere? Imagine [empty, sphere, sphere, empty]

Comment: @Medix2 All spaces that surround the sphere are equal distance from the sphere, so you can pick any.

Comment: Entering one side of the sphere makes the other side 10ft away, how does this work with the line " to the nearest unoccupied space"? The nearest spaces are surely within 5ft?

Comment: @SeriousBri I think the language is supposed to mean nearest to the sphere, not nearest to the creature. Remember that grids are a variant rule.

Comment: Interesting take, I see the logic. Don't know if I agree, but I see it.